# How to pass routeparams value in model window angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

In my project I am trying to implement modal window for the edit screen. I have listed screen where users need to select one row from the list and click the modify button. I need to open the edit screen in modal window. If I call the normal screen I will be using this:

```
$location.path(url)  (i.e) url -- >  page1/:id --> page1/3
```

Which is working fine. It's redirecting to the corresponding page with data.

but in modal window we call like this:

```
 exDialog.openPrime({
     scope: $scope,
     template: urlAppBase+templateurl,
     controller: controllerName,
     width: '1120px',
     animation: false,
     grayBackground: false            
 });
```

How do you send params value to the controller?

or

How do you open modal window based on url?

Answer (score 0):

in stateParams

```
  .state('users', {
    url:'/users/:userId',
  ....
  })
```

if url is = '/#/users/2', in controller do as follows

```
  var usrID = $stateParams.userId;
```

in RouteParams,

```
  .when('/users/:userID', {
   ....
  })
```

if url is = '/#/users/2', in controller do as follows

```
  var usrID = $routeParams.userID
```

Now open the dialog.. based on url... Also pass the paramvalues using resolve in the dialog..

```
     $scope.openDialog = function() {
       var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       templateUrl: 'someviews.html' ,
       controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
       scope : $scope,
       windowClass:'center-modal',
       resolve:{
          SomeVal : function(){
            var urlParamval = $routeParams.userID;
            return urlParamval ;
          }
       }
     });
  };
```

Access the value in the template html as {{SomeVal}}

Comment: What I asked is how to open model window with url?